# Remove redundant timestamps from csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-science

I have created a CSV file from the recording of different sensors using pandas DataFrame. The CSV file basically looks like this:

[image: what the csv file looks like, simplified]

I would like to get rid of the redundant timestamps and instead have all sensor entries that share a timestamp appear in the same row (for example x2 and x3 in the image).
Also, the labels that share a timestamp are always identical, but would need to be reduced as well.

So far, I've come across the `drop_duplicate()` function which only drops entire rows.

Edit: here's a text version of the example above:

```
timestamp,sensor_a,sensor_b,sensor_c,label
1,x1,,,0
2,,x2,,0
2,,,x3,0
3,x4,,,1
4,,,,1
5,,x6,,1
5,,,x7,1
```

Comment: what is the content of the empty spaces is it `` or None or what else? I think its better to give the dataframe in text as you have.

Comment: I added the example as a text. I double checked with the real dataframe I am working on - the empty spaces are just empty as in the text example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you store the data in a text file `sensors.txt`, so we con consolidate the data based on `timestamp` according to the following code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sensors.txt', delimiter=',', header=0)

df2 = df.groupby('timestamp').ffill()
df2['timestamp'] = df['timestamp']
df2 = df2.groupby('timestamp').bfill()
df2['timestamp'] = df['timestamp']
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()

df = df2[['timestamp', 'sensor_a', 'sensor_b', 'sensor_c', 'label']]
print(df)
```

output

```
   timestamp sensor_a sensor_b sensor_c  label
0          1       x1      NaN      NaN      0
1          2      NaN       x2       x3      0
3          3       x4      NaN      NaN      1
4          4      NaN      NaN      NaN      1
5          5      NaN       x6       x7      1
```

further editing will be based on your questions in the comments below

Good Luck